# Silverlight combobox performance improvements already using virtualization

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, combobox

I am working with a combobox to show a list of items with a checkbox. The issue I am facing is that performance on showing (rendering I guess) the list of items when opening the combobox list, slows down when increasing the number of items (e.g. 300 items take around 3 seconds, and I will need to show 1000s).

This is how the code looks like:

**MultiSelComboBoxStyle.xaml**

```
    <ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

    <Style x:Key="CheckBoxListBoxItemStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Grid x:Name="RootElement">
                        <!--<CheckBox ClickMode="Press" Content="{Binding Path=Name}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />-->
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" Content="{Binding Text}" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="MSMMultiSelComboBoxStyle" TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,2,25,2"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Once"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border x:Name="ContentPresenterBorder">
                            <Grid>
                                <ToggleButton x:Name="DropDownToggle" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                    <Path x:Name="BtnArrow" Data="F1 M 301.14,-189.041L 311.57,-189.041L 306.355,-182.942L 301.14,-189.041 Z " HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="4" Margin="0,0,6,0" Stretch="Uniform" Width="8">
                                        <Path.Fill>
                                            <SolidColorBrush x:Name="BtnArrowColor" Color="#FF333333"/>
                                        </Path.Fill>
                                    </Path>
                                </ToggleButton>
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="tb" Text=" "/>
                                </ContentPresenter>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="DisabledVisualElement" IsHitTestVisible="false" Opacity="0" RadiusY="3" RadiusX="3"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualElement" IsHitTestVisible="false" Margin="1" Opacity="0" RadiusY="2" RadiusX="2" StrokeThickness="1"/>
                        <Border x:Name="ValidationErrorElement" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="1" Visibility="Collapsed">
                            <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                <ToolTip x:Name="validationTooltip" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Placement="Right" PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" >
                                    <ToolTip.Triggers>
                                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Canvas.Loaded">
                                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsHitTestVisible" Storyboard.TargetName="validationTooltip">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                                <System:Boolean>true</System:Boolean>
                                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </BeginStoryboard>
                                        </EventTrigger>
                                    </ToolTip.Triggers>
                                </ToolTip>
                            </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                            <Grid Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="12" Margin="1,-4,-4,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="12">
                                <Path Data="M 1,0 L6,0 A 2,2 90 0 1 8,2 L8,7 z" Margin="1,3,0,0"/>
                                <Path Data="M 0,0 L2,0 L 8,6 L8,8" Margin="1,3,0,0"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <Popup x:Name="Popup">
                            <Border x:Name="PopupBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto">
                                <Border.Background>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                        <!--<GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFFEFEFE" Offset="1"/>
                                    -->
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Border.Background>
                                <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" BorderThickness="0" Padding="1">
                                    <!--<ItemsPresenter/>-->
                                    <ListBox x:Name="lstBox" SelectionMode="Multiple" ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding ItemsSource}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource CheckBoxListBoxItemStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
                                        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                                <VirtualizingStackPanel  />
                                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                                    </ListBox>
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </Border>
                        </Popup>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

**DeskCombo.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="Apama.UI.Surveillance.Controls.DeskCombo"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="28" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="MultiSelComboBoxStyle.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <ComboBox x:Name="cbDesk"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource MSMMultiSelComboBoxStyle}" >
            <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And this is how I bind the items to the combobox:

```
List<Desk> desks = new List<Desk>();

        desks.Add(new Desk() { DeskId = UIConstants.SELECT_ALL_TEXT, DeskName = UIConstants.SELECT_ALL_TEXT, DimDeskId = UIConstants.SELECT_ALL_ID });
        desks.AddRange(data.Desks.Values);

        _items = new StaticDataStore<Desk>(GetItemName, desks, AddAll);
        ComboBoxItems = new ComboBoxDataItemCollection(desks.Select(dk => new ComboBoxDataItem(dk.DimDeskId) { Text = dk.DeskName }));
        ComboBoxItems.Owner = this;

        // Bind
        cbDesk.ItemsSource = ComboBoxItems.ToList();
```

I have done some research and I thought it may be something related to the virtualization of the items, but I included the tags in the style template listbox and in the combobox itself and didn't see any change.

Is there anything else I can check? Any idea would be much appreciated.

Comment: There is [no noticeable delay](https://imgur.com/cxJh6qg) in a 1,000 items combo box, using a standard, clear-cut, textbook, MVVM binding. And also using default combo box style. So, i suggest you to do the same before you start customizing anything. Your binding seems to take quite a bit of twists and turns before calling that `ToList()` at the end, which most likely should not even be necessary.

Comment: BTW, it runs just as fast in a 10,000 items combo box as well.

Comment: I need the combobox to use items with checkbox. The rest of the customization is absolutely expendable. How could I modify the template to keep only the customization of the items?

Comment: I'm not suggesting you to toss away your customization. I'm suggesting you to do the troubleshooting yourself so you can narrow it down and ask a specific enough question. Simply define `<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. Actually the final solution I took was to simply use the ItemTemplate in the combobox. See the answer below.

Comment: You're welcome, but...:O)  1) God forbid the business logic in your view model  needs the selected value in your combo box... because now you set it to null... 2) Not to even mention the questionable UX  of leaving the user in the dark about what or if something was selected. 3) even if it's really necessary hiding that information from the user, which is a stretch,  that's not how you do it anyway...

Comment: BTW, you never mentioned hiding the selected value in your original question anyway... you just added this in your _"answer"_ below out of nowhere...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the day I got rid of the MultiSelComboBoxStyle.xaml and changed the DeskCombo.xaml this way:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Apama.UI.Surveillance.Controls.DeskCombo"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="28" d:DesignWidth="400">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <ComboBox x:Name="cbDesk"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" DropDownClosed="hideSelected">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" Content="{Binding Text}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

I included the "hideSelected" callback because I don't want the dropdow to show any value when closed. That callback just does this:

```
private void hideSelected(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cbDesk.SelectedItem = null;
    }
```

As my prefered choice for the style is to keep the website look and feel, I am good getting rid of the MultiSelComboBoxStyle.xaml. Most of this file function was to include the checkbox items and hide the value "selected" in the combobox when it is closed, but somthing inside that code was messing up the performance.